# How to prevent Chrome coming into focus when hovering over Selenium Element variable?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, pytest

I've recently been writing Python scripts using Visual Studio Code which are used to test the front end of an application I develop for.  When debugging, I like to hover over variables to see what they contain, but if it's a Selenium element, when I hover over it in Visual Studio Code, Chrome will come into focus for some reason, and I can't see my Visual Studio Code window anymore since Chrome takes over my screen.

For example, I have this Python excerpt:

```py
errorMessage = self.driver.find_element(*Endpoints.ERROR_TEXT)
if errorMessage.text == expectedError:
    pass
else:
    assert False, "Expected Error Message Does Not Matched With Actual Error Message"
```

If I were to hover over `errorMessage` or `errorMessage.text` when debugging the script, Chrome will take focus and take up the entirety of my screen.

How can I prevent Chrome from doing this?

Comment: Could you start chrome as headless within selenium?

Comment: @pyknight202 I might be able to, though I don't know what other implications that may have.  I'm more of a "side dev" when it comes to these tests (I primarily write C# code for the API these python files also test).  I believe there was _some reason_ why it doesn't run headless.  There is a lot of weird table scrolling that these scripts do via looking for specific column names XPaths, and I thought I was told that this, among other things, was one reason why it can't be run headless.

Comment: Hmm.. there might be some way to prevent the chrome window from focusing. I found this post that might help you: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/39547/selenium-how-to-prevent-a-just-started-chrome-window-from-receiving-focus